# GWT UiBinder TabPanel

Tags: gwt, uibinder, tabpanel

How to define TabPanel in UiBinder in GWT. What's difference between TabPanel and TabLayoutPanel. Where to find additional info about TabPanel uibinder parameters.

Answer (score 9):

Sample:

```
<g:TabPanel ui:field="mainTab">
    <g:Tab text="Header #1">
        <g:FlowPanel ui:field="tabPanel1"/>
    </g:Tab>
    <g:Tab text="Header #2">
        <g:FlowPanel ui:field="tabPanel2"/>
    </g:Tab>
</g:TabPanel>
```

There are two main differents in TabPanel and TabLayoutPanel:

1. TabLayoutPanel requires ProvidesResize container, TabPanel have no additional requirements
2. TabPanel translates to simple html table, TabLayoutPanel translates to pack of divs with relativly complex layout.

You can find more info about TabPanel in TabPanelParser class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759757/gwt-uibinder-tab-panel) for the difference between TabPanel and TabLayoutPanel